# Is there anyway to view executed JS functions names for certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, scroll, reverse-engineering

I need to understand how some site loads additional content when I finished scrolling. I need it for loading that content by my own injected JS without scrolls.

The way I see is to press somewhere some button to start recording functions calls, then I scroll down, new content loads, then I stop recording and looking for something useful.

If you know some better ways to track down needed functions please explain those.

I can use any browser for debugging.

Comment: You can always use Chrome's DevTools. Just drop a `debugger;` where you want in your code and start following the script execution step by step.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879997/1270789) is what you might be able to use?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who comment. I think I got some idea on how to do it. My question is appears to be a dupe, so I accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this using the Chrome DevTools XHR breakpoints.  You'll have to do it in two steps.

First, open DevTools and go to the `Network` tab.  Watch for the remote address that the scroller is loading data from.  Then, go to the `Sources` tab and add an XHR breakpoint with that address.  Chrome will stop *in code* when a request to that address is made.

[image: XHR breakpoint]

Comment: Thank you, this is something interesting. Now I just need to understand where new data comes from :O