# Add callback to black-box function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently writing a userscript for a site. The site has an update function called `updateBOB` which is called every so often and updates the UI.

My userscript adds a button to the DOM, which is removed by said `updateBOB` function, hence I want to either

- Add a callback to this function.
- Change the definition of this function.

I couldn't find a way to make option 1 work, so I tried option 2 like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        addButton();
        let oldBOB = updateBOB;
        updateBOB = function(){
            oldBOB.apply(oldBOB, arguments);
            addButton();
        }
}
```

However, it seems like updateBOB is updated in function scope, but the change does not stay. I never trigger the addButton function with.

Keep in mind that I cannot change the source code of the site, I just know what function is necessary to keep track of via-via.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you might not be able to reach it. you would have to monitor what you can see and react accordingly. maybe there's a DOM prop you can watch, or maybe you can wrap the XHR constructor to get ajax notifications, something like that

Comment: Damn, I think I can indeed watch the DOM and add a handler there... Not sure if it'll work, but thanks!

Comment: Maybe `updateBOB` is replaced by something else before it gets executed? [Try the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126723/javascript-execution-tracking-in-chrome-how)