# Inspect where html pop is coming from

Tags: html

I have this annoying popup where it only displays the number 1. tried to search it manually in the system but there is too much others ones. is there a way where i could inspect a popup?

[image]

Comment: just an advice: avoid having many debug alerts that says "1", add the file name/line next to it so you can trace them

Comment: Search for "alert("? Seems like a javascript, so might find among the sources.

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126723/javascript-execution-tracking-in-chrome-how

Comment: What I'd do is open all files in your text editor and do 'ctrl+f' and search for `alert("1");` or `alert('1');` in all opened files, not much else you can do really

Comment: @kry Or for "alert" if "alert(" fails, since parentheses might not come immediately after function name

Comment: Also following on from what @Kaddath said...you should try use console.log() instead of alert() for debugging and it will give you the line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your web page click on view page source by clicking on mouse right click or by ctrl+u with keyboard shortcode.
and then find:

```
alert(
```

and comment all alert box into your code.

Comment: thanks, found the issue. weridly its in the my sql rows thats why i could not find it at first

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Get id of that alert and search it manually. To get id, follow the image boxes or **press CTRL+Shift+C and press ok**. You will find function call in element section. go to the function and get your alert box.