# Chrome dev tools: Stop at first JS line after button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to set breakpoints in chrome dev tools.

But is there a way to stop at the first JS line which gets executed after a button click without setting a break point?

That's how I would like it to be:

1. tell chrome to stop at first JS line which gets executed
2. do some action (for example press a button)
3. Chrome stops at the first JS line and shows me this line.

Comment: In the `Sources` panel of devtools expand "Event listener breakpoints", then "Script", then select "Script first statement".

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126723/javascript-execution-tracking-in-chrome-how) is a very similar question, and answered.

Comment: Also another nice little tip, you can also tell your browser in code to stop by using the `debugger;` statement.  I use this technique most of the time, this is because during build / line numbers, even files that get bundled can change.  So stored breakpoints end up been useless, I combine this with some debug flags I can turn on an off.  And production builds can remove these too.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you! "SCript / Script first statement" does what I need. If you write an answer, then I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

A very terse answer: In Chrome Inspector, switch to the `Sources` tab and hit `F8`.